# Is there a difference between concat(), "=" and "+="

Tags: javascript, performance, concatenation

I was wondering if there is any difference in performance between the following statements to concatinate two strings `str1='a'` and `str2='b'`

```
str1 = str1 + str2;
```

or

```
str1 += str2;
```

or

```
var res = str1.concat(str2);
```

I have tried the following to measure the performance but the output seems to vary a lot from one execution to another for the same statement.

```
var str1='a', str2='b';
var old_time=new Date();
for (var i=0; i<=1000000 ; i++){    
    str1=str1+str2;      // change this one with the other statements
}
var new_time=new Date();
console.log(new_time - old_time);
```

Comment: did you create a [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/)?

Comment: No I didn't know about the existence of this tool

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference of + operator and concat() method in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465804/what-is-the-difference-of-operator-and-concat-method-in-javascript)

Comment: The performance will probably vary on different JS engines. You should first evaluate whether you actually have a situation where the performance matters, and if it does, you should do a systematic test using something like jsperf (as @Aᴍɪʀ mentioned).

Comment: This kind of micro-optimization is rarely worth fretting over. You’re better off using the implementation that is the clearest. In this case, I would opt for version 1 or 2. See http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat): *"It is strongly recommended that assignment operators (+, +=) are used instead of the concat() method. See this [performance test](http://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join).*"

Comment: I haven't voted, but this is [a link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: IMO not much more needs to be said and the link comes from a definitive source, clearly answering the question: (*I was wondering if there is any difference in performance between the following statements*).

Answer (score 1):

Whereas

```
str1 += str2;
```

would appear to be a tad faster than `str1 = str1 + str2;` BUT since strings are immutable you cannot reuse old reference from `str1`. example:

```
str0 = str1;   // duplicate reference
str1 += str2;
```

`str0` *lust* keep its old value (before concatenation with `str2`) so after the concatenation, `str1` is a new object (unlike with mutable objects where in-place concatenation *can* be faster because we'd expect `s0` to change as well)

I'd still prefer the `+=` syntax because it's more concise and easier to grasp.

Comment: The VM can easily and legally optimize `x = x + y` into `x += y`, especially for primitives like most strings. Since strings are immutable (typically copy-on-write and may use some form of ropes), the bit about temporary objects is also misleading and a copy will often be made (or, depending on the VM, may never be made).

Comment: @ssube I thought that over and heavily edited my answer because I realized how it was highly incorrect in the javascript context.